# Get private variable within its own class with getter or direct with name?

Tags: java, coding-style

whats the more prefered way to get private variables within the same Class.

for instance we have this code:

```
public Class TestClass
{
    private String name;

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }
```

...

```
    public String someMethod()
    {
        return getInfo(name);
        or
        return getInfo(getName());
    }
}
```

...

so whats the prefered way, to get the private variable within the same class with its **name** or with its **getter**?

Update:
The getter will always just return name.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Conventions: use getters/setters WITHIN the class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8466790/java-conventions-use-getters-setters-within-the-class)

Answer (score 1):

Well, this I think is a preference/situation related question. If you call directly the field you will get a better time because you don't do an additional method call which are very fast anyway, and maybe be a little more concise. But if you use a getter you can add another layer of abstraction, and do some other stuff in there, like returning another value instead of the default is the field is not set, something like:

```
int getAge() {
   return (age < 18) ? 18 : age;
}
```

Also this will help in the case of objects to avoid to return null, like:

```
Stuff getStuff() {
    if(stuff == null) {
        return Stuff.NULL_OBJECT;
    }
}
```

Please beware that Stuff is my class and the NULL_OBJECT field is a Null object pattern implementation, and my example doesn't have any synchronization.

This being said, I always use the direct field access approach if the situation doesn't require something extravagant.

Answer (score 1):

Preference will depend on context.  In your case above where the getter simply returns the variable, many developers will tend to return the variable directly.  However, if your getter is more complicated or believe it might change in the future, then the use of the getter might be preferred.  It all depends on what `name` represents, what `getName()` returns and what `getInfo(...)` expects.

Comment: The getter just returns name any case, any time. Whats the better aproach?

Comment: My point here is that better is subjective.  If you expect your getter to change or get more complicated in the future then it might be a better choice.  If all you are doing with the getter is returing the field, then I, personally, would go for the direct field access as being more readable.

Comment: Thank you for your comprehensive answer