# When would you ever want a public instance variable?

Tags: java, instance-variables

I was coding up my own implementation of a LinkedList yesterday. I was doing something like this:

```
public class Node
{
    Node next;
    int value;

    public Node()
    {
       next = null
       value = 0;
    }
}
```

Then when using the `Node` I was doing `node.next` and `node.value`. Then I realized - wait, what the heck am I doing? These instance variables should be `private` and then I should be accessing with getters() and setters() like `getNext()` and `setValue()`.

This led me to wonder, when is anything **other** than a `private` instance variable desired?

Comment: This answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8466886/758446 gives some details on exceptions to the standard (desirable?) behavior of using getters and setters religiously. Although I think it is mostly referring to your choice of access from within the class, where I suppose you'd have your choice still.

Comment: If your `getter` is simple `return value;` and your `setter` is simply `setValue(int a) { value = a; }` (so you have zero logic in either), there's not much wrong with the variable being public.  With that said, it's likely that your class will have private variables that must be accessed through setters and getters, so for uniformity, you may as well make everything the same.

Comment: Call me old-school but I don't see the advantage of using getters or setters at all unless you want to trigger side-effects or do some validation. It's just extra, unnecessary length and parentheses.

Comment: But one advantage to using even empty `getters` and `setters` is that if you need to add validation logic or side-effects in the future, then you only have to write that code in one spot (in the getter/setter) and all other code that already had to access the variable through the getter/setter is now using that validation logic.

Comment: When you trust yourself

Comment: In python you can use decorators to have your getters and setters and still have access to the raw "private" version usually denoted by an underscore before the name in the event that you *really know what you're doing.* Other editors of a shared code base that you are the primary author of might not fit in that category, but they'd still have the option.  You can do similar stuff in Java.

Comment: @Kevin Most programmers don't like having to check whether a value is null all the time.  Encapsulating a value in get- and set-methods allows the object to make guarantees, such as guaranteeing that the value will never be null (or that an int value is never negative, etc.)

Comment: @VGR That would go under the "validation" I mentioned. I suppose I've been spoiled lately working in Objective C, where (1) calling on a null pointer does nothing (no-op/returns null/0), and (2) if you want to add a getter/setter, you just name it right, no external changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technically, you're asking two questions:  The title question, "When is it appropriate to have a public instance field," and your final sentence, "When is it appropriate to have a non-private instance field."

When is it appropriate to have a public instance field?  Just about everyone knows the answer is almost never.  I think they occasionally can be appropriate in very small value classes, which behave like simple C structs.  A good example would be java.awt.Point and java.awt.Dimension.

Those are in fact especially good examples, because they ended up evolving to use accessor methods despite their simplicity, which is a good lesson:  Even a class that seems so simple that public fields might seem acceptable has a real possibility of becoming something that requires encapsulation.  (Point and Dimension continue to retain those public fields for backward compatibility.)

When is it appropriate to have non-private instance fields?  Most people don't take advantage of the fact that fields and methods (and classes) with no access modifier are package-private, but package-private fields can be useful in a lot of situations.  Since they're only accessed by the same package, it will often be the case that it's your code and you can trust yourself not to do "bad things" that would corrupt your objects.  I'd say there are considerably more legitimate uses for package-private fields than for public fields.

That said, the Point/Dimension rule still applies:  There have been many times when I thought I could get away with package-private fields, only to later realize I needed encapsulation via get- and set-methods.

Protected fields probably get used far more than they should.  There's rarely a big gain to let a subclass modify state directly instead of going through a method, in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

When you don't actually *need* to protect them from arbitrary access or changes (such as when the value is allowed to take *any* integer, or a simple null mapping of "value retrieved" to "value in object"), it makes little sense to wrap a getter or setter around it.

The code can sometimes look more natural if that's the case, using:

```
object.value = 42;
```

rather than:

```
object.setValue (42);
```

(though the difference to *my* eyes is minimal).

Having said that, I *still* prefer getters and setters since, if at some point in the future you *need* to incorporate logic into the member, changing a public member to a getter/setter for that member will break the API for that class, involving changes to all clients using it.

This can include (but is in no way limited to):

- restricting the values you can set the member to. For example, restricting the age of an object to between 0 and 13.7 billion years :-)
- deriving the value being extracted, such as calculating Fahrenheit temperature from a Celsius member.
- having side effects to setting a value, such as changing a file name involving preloading some of the file into a cache.

Answer (score 1):

The classic example is a class to represent two-dimensional mathematical points.

```
public class Point {
    public float x;
    public float y;

    public Point( float x, float y ) {
        x = x;
        y = y;
    }

    public void scale( float c ) {
        x *= c;
        y *= c;
    }

    public void rotate( float angle, Point center ) {
       // whatever this logic is; I forget
    }   
}
```

A `Point` is really just a container for two floats that can vary arbitrarily. You aren't really going to hurt anything by allows access to `x` and `y` directly, rather than forcing the user to go through getters and setters. At the same time, some operations like scaling and rotation are common enough that it's worth creating a class that provides methods for doing the necessary math on the coordinates.

---

Please forgive (or better yet, correct) any syntax or other errors in the code. I haven't written any Java in ages.

Comment: I'll forgive a lot, but not the messy mathematical thinking that comes up with rotating a zero-dimension point through a certain angle, at least without a reference point to rotate around :-)

Comment: OK, that was pretty glaring.

Answer (score 0):

You must look at access specifiers in Java. For quick reference: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html