# Overriding equals method: why use methods to compare fields

Tags: java, equals

I've been reading about how to override the equals method and noticed that my book uses methods to compare fields instead of comparing fields directly.  After reading about getters and setters, I'm still having a hard time understanding why one would use a getter in this situation.  The book defines a class, Employee, as follows:

```
class Employee {

    private String lastName;
    private String firstName;

    public Employee(String lastName, String firstName){
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName(){
        return lastName;
    }

    public String getFirstName(){
        return firstName;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object obj){
        if(this == obj)
            return true;
        if(this == null)
            return false;
        if(this.getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Employee emp = (Employee) obj;
        return
            this.firstName.equals(emp.getFirstName())
                && this.lastName.equals(emp.getLastName());

    }
}
```

Is there a reason one would use the method getFirstName() to compare this.firstName with emp.firstName instead of directly comparing them?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [is getter method call to access variable better than direct variable access within a class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23695683/is-getter-method-call-to-access-variable-better-than-direct-variable-access-with)

Comment: Maybe just a feeling of justice: privacy for the other seems appropriate. It is weird that one object even can alter another object*s field if that is of the same class.

Comment: You meant `if(obj == null)`, not `if(this == null)`.

Comment: I think since null is not a member of the Object class the equals method doesn't like to accept it.  On the other hand null.equals(object) throws an exception too so I'm not totally sure what's going on with that part either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on the design you want/need. The only valid reason I've found to use getters over direct fields to implement `equals` is because the object reference you're comparing with may be a proxy generated by another library like cglib and the field has a `null` value and it's only available through getters. This works for example when working with a JPA implementation like Hibernate. Another (very odd) example is if you pass a subclass of this one and the getters have their own business logic inside.

If you're sure you're not going to use such libraries in your project, then do the comparison using the fields.