# Is it proper to call a getter for the value of a variable for a class instanace within methods for that class in Java?

Tags: java, methods, standards, getter

I am writing a non-static method for a Java class that uses the value of a class variable for the class instance that is calling the method as one of the factors in determining the output. Is it standard practice to call the getter method for that variable from within the class method, or simply type the name of the variable?

For example, consider a class with the following constructor:

```
public BoardSpaceSymmetry(int boardSize, int xIndex, int yIndex) {
    this.boardSize = boardSize;
    this.xIndex = xIndex;
    this.yIndex = yIndex;
    this.xMax = xIndex + boardSize - 1;
    this.yMax = yIndex + boardSize - 1;
}
```

If I am writing a method for an instance of the BoardSpaceSymmetry class that uses the values of xIndex and yIndex, which of these would be a more standard way to write the method?

Option A:

```
public boolean isSpaceOnDiagonal (int xCoord, int yCoord) {
    if ((xCoord - getxIndex()) == (yCoord - getyIndex())) {
        return true;
    }
    if(getyMax() - yCoord == xCoord - getxIndex()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Option B:

```
public boolean isSpaceOnDiagonal (int xCoord, int yCoord) {
    if ((xCoord - xIndex) == (yCoord - yIndex)) {
        return true;
    }
    if(yMax - yCoord == xCoord - xIndex) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Option C:

```
public boolean isSpaceOnDiagonal (int xCoord, int yCoord) {
    if ((xCoord - this.xIndex) == (yCoord - this.yIndex)) {
        return true;
    }
    if(this.yMax - yCoord == xCoord - this.xIndex) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Option B and Option C are semantically equivalent. I would suggest using Option A, it might come in handy if we want to stub this object in the future.

Comment: This question is duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23695683/is-getter-method-call-to-access-variable-better-than-direct-variable-access-with