# Calling getter within the class?

Tags: java, inheritance, getter-setter

I want to know if it is okay to call getter-methods to access class variables? Or is it better to call them directly?
Is there any best practice?

And what about inherited classes: Should they call getter or should the variable changed to be protected?

Comment: [Check answer here](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/181567/should-the-methods-of-a-class-call-its-own-getters-and-setters)

Comment: I agree with the accepted answer of the question above cited by @gtgaxiola and I hate when eclipse replaces my code by getters and setters when it generates them

Comment: btw i disagree with the accepted answer of the duplicated question, my dissent is at http://stackoverflow.com/a/8466867/217324

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, it's better to always use getters, even within the class. The reason for that is that some getters perform logic beyond simply returning the instance variable.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, What matters most is that access outside the class be accessed by well defined getters/setters, it's a judgement call on whether you need to access them directly.  The internal plumbing sometimes needs the raw value not to mention the overhead and unintended consequences of lazy gets etc...