# Cons of using setters during construction of classes?

Tags: java, class, constructor, setter

*Please note: I'm asking for the cons not whether or not the pros out weigh the cons of vice-versa so this is not opinion based.*

I was working though a Java tutorial and the tutorial recommend not using setters during construction (even if the setter logic would make sense in the construction of an instance). I was wondering why this would be a bad idea. The tutorial made a rather vague mention about inheritance issues latter on.

Also if a setter is mainly validation could I just take out the validation as a separate function and then be able to call the function in a constructor without having the same issues as using the setter directly?

Comment: I concur with Nathan that the only real con of method invocation from the constructor exists when the class is subclassed, and when the subclass overrides that non-final method.  I do not see any issues with calling methods from constructors if the class is final, or will never be subclassed.  The tutorial should not have spoken about only setters having a potential problem; the concept can occur with any method called from a constructor.

Comment: some links that seem kind of related: [Java Conventions: use getters/setters WITHIN the class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8466790/java-conventions-use-getters-setters-within-the-class/8466867#8466867), [Flaw: constructor does real work](http://misko.hevery.com/code-reviewers-guide/flaw-constructor-does-real-work/)

Answer (score 2):

The major point (which is probably what your tutorial was trying to get at about inheritance) is that when you're constructing your object if you're calling methods then if those setters are overridden in a subclass then that can cause problems. The overridden version will call subclass code where the subclass may not be initialized yet (since the subclass initializers and constructor haven't run yet), so the initialization may fail or have unexpected consequences. If you limit the calling of instance methods during construction to call only final methods then you can avoid this issue.

There are people who do put validation in their setters but it is probably not a best practice. Validation can be added using annotations, or moved into separate dedicated validation objects, where you can control under what circumstances the validation gets invoked. For instance, in JPA the persistent entities' getters and setters are used by the ORM implementation and validation code within them can get in the way. I would suggest looking for ways to remove the validation from setters.