# Should data members be accessed directly or using getter method?

Tags: java, class, oop

Suppose I have a class `Circle` with a data member `float radius`. I have a getter and setter method as `getRadius()` and `setRadius(float r)`. I use the latter to assign the radius value. Now, after the assignment, should I use the value of `radius` in calculations (in a method called `areaCircle()`) by directly accessing it or should I call the getter method instead?

Comment: you can use just 'radius'

Comment: You may just use radius. Better go through basic tutorial like https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html

Comment: It dosn't matter what you use because `getRadius()` will return `radius`, but if you're within the class then you should use `radius`.

Comment: Furthermore, you may want to rename your method to something like "calculateArea()" to make it clearer. No need to mention "Circle" in your methods, since the method belongs to the Circle class anyway. Whose area else should it compute.

Comment: @Matt: very good advice.

Answer (score 7):

You can just use radius as it's defined within the same class. Get and set methods are for getting or setting a variable from another class/object.

Comment: @Prem Even using getRadius() does no harm from within the class. Its just that you 'may' use 'radius' as it is.

Comment: @abksrv there is a difference. It depends upon whether you are intending the getter to be overridable in subclasses. If neither the class nor the getter are final, you might get different behaviour depending upon whether you access the field or call the getter.

Answer (score 2):

You can, and really, you ought to use the class field `radius` directly.

Having "getters" and "setters" by rote achieves little more than code bloat and a defeat of encapsulation. It's also makes your code less thread safe: what happens if one thread is computing the area while another is changing the radius through the "setter"? It can even, on occasions, be *harmful*: a child class might override the "getter" or "setter"; remember that all non-`static` functions are "virtual" in Java.

It's far better is to set all your fields in a *constructor*, and provide a "getter" if you really must.

And we're no longer in the 1970s. Stop using `float`. It's probably *slower* than a `double` due to internal conversions to and from the latter.

Comment: Well, SO is based on opinions, not on facts :-/. I don't think that using the getters and setters of the same class will have any advantages over accessing attributes directly in more sophisticated examples than the computation of areas. But that's an opinion, too :)

Answer (score 0):

If exists getters and setters, then should be used always even inside class. Of course if getter and setter do something more in method then it must be considered if it fullfils Your needs.

Should be used not means must be used. You can use property `radius` directly ( only inside class if property is private - and should be ) but in good practice is to use getter and setter.

So using property directly is possible, but I recommend use `get` and `set` because it give more flexibility and can do something more than tipical assign or get.

For example if in first place setter only sets something, but after a while setter is changed to do something more.

```
 setName(name){

     this.name="name";
 }
```

So in code `setName("John");` is equal `name="John"`. But imagine that after a while we want to set another property when `name` is set:

```
 setName(name){

     this.name="name";
     this.nameIsSet=true;
 }
```

another example **( Listener pattern )**:

```
setName(name){

     this.name="name";
     this.listener.nameChanged(this.name); //we call listener that variable changed
 }
```

Then programmer needs to find every assigment like `name="John"` in class and refactor it to new behavior. If only `setName` is used then no code change must be done.

Of course everything depends from need and is possible that setting, getting property from outside do something more and different and it not fullfils our need inside class.

Comment: It's a dangerous thing to modify other attributes than the one specified in the respective setter method, especially when this may have side effects that I have no clue of as a "user" of your code.

Comment: @Matt if so getter and setter whould be only methods for one line code - and always the same. I don't think Your opinion is right. If getter and setter do something totally not linked with variable yes this has side effects and should be not done. Tipical situation for do something more in setter is for example Listener pattern, if we set variable it call some callback.

Comment: @Matt i see my answer is pretty the same as accepted answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8466790/java-conventions-use-getters-setters-within-the-class

Comment: No offense. I meant it is dangerous regarding the respective case. Your example is just a snippet, I could extend that class, where setting "nameIsSet" in the setName method might be really evil, just the same I could extend that class where it's perfectly valid to do like you did it, though. I'm just saying that it's hard for a beginner to tell the difference.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether or not you have declared radius private. If you use getters and setters to access it you should have declared radius private because else the encapsulation is broken.

an exception to this might be when the method "areaCircle()" you mentioned is in the same class, in that case it will be able directly access the private radius attribute without the need for using getters and setters.

FYI:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_encapsulation.htm

Answer (score 0):

If your value may vary overtime (for example a timer) then use the getter.

Answer (score -1):

If you create a private method you can use the radius without getters or setters, but in public mehtodes it's better to use getters and setters.

If it's possible i would use getters and setters. These are better and you will get as less errors as without them.

Comment: Can you prove your two assertions? 1. Better to use getters/setters in public methods than in private ones 2. Less errors with getter/setter

Comment: public methods has access to private properties Your answer has no sense.

Comment: You will need public methods to call them from outside the class, so it is possible to become more errors. It's more risky to use the variable without getters and setters because you have to handle the nullpointer and other singularities each time new. If you use getters and setters you can handle these singularities once. So you don't need to worry every time.