# Java: use directly parent class field or using getters

Tags: java

I would like to know what is the recommended way to get parent class fields.

Is it better to set parent class fields `protected` and use directly the fields, or set fields to `private` and get them using getters in child classes?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8466790/java-conventions-use-getters-setters-within-the-class

Comment: 6 of one or half dozen of the other, `getters` as in any situation can be useful for debugging and facilitating extra functionality, if neither of those things are a concern then i'd just make the fields you want to expose `protected`.

Comment: Always please [search first](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+java+parent+gettter+private+fields+or+protected)